# How Can I Limit CPU core to specific thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, udp, threadpool, multicore

In my program, UDP data is sent and received regularly. If only this one program runs on the entire computer, the result is normal. However, if other operations are performed at the same time (such as opening a PDF document), UDP communication will be affected, and the reception timeout will occur. By observing the task manager, when performing other operations, the CPU usage will increase temporarily, which will affect the running of my program. Since my computer is multi-core (12 cores), I tried to bind my key thread to a certain core, but it still doesn't work, other threads will still be assigned to this core by the system.

```
keyThread.IdealProcessor = 9;
keyThread.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)512;
```

I think what I need is to bind a certain CPU core to the key thread of the program, not the other way around. But I did not find a way to do this.

Add some details about my program.

```
timer.interval = 10;    //10ms
localSocket.Connect(remotePoint);
localSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 10;    //10ms
private void Timer_Ticked() 
{     
    byte[] requestFrame = new byte[1024];     
    requestFrame = frameManager.GenerateFrame();     
    localSocket.Send(requestFrame);     
    try     
    {         
        byte[] responseFrame = new byte[1024];         
        localSocket.Receive(responseFrame);     
    }     
    catch (Exception)     
    {         
        Console.WriteLine("receive timeout");     
    } 
}
```

I add new code to set the priority of the process to Realtime, and set the priority of the thread to Highest, but still didn't work, when I perform other operation in the computer(like open a PDF file or open the Chrome), my program is affected.

I observe the task manager of Windows 10, when I perform an operation (such as opening a PDF document), there will be a peak in the usage of all CPU cores. Can I specify a CPU core to work only for my program and not be used by other programs?

Comment: How are you sending and receiving the packets. Can we see that code? We might be able to use .NET Task Scheduler to our avantage instead of doing it by manually assigning affinity for the thread. Also cpu affinity isnt garunteed and execution is ultimately up to the OS

Comment: How long is the reception timeout? Is it in the range of milliseconds?

Comment: What is the `timer`? Is it a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` control?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Not the system's timer, it's a timer provided in a dll file, and its precision is 1ms.

Comment: Does this timer provide any protection against overlapping invocations of the `Ticked` event?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias sorry, I don't know that, the timer provide properties include `Interval`,  `IsRunning`, and method include `start()`,  `stop()`, and the event `Ticked`，no more else.

Comment: Is the `Ticked` event always invoked on the same thread, or it is invoked on different `ThredPool` threads each time? You can check it out by logging the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` on each invocation. I am asking all that because your current setup looks a bit sketchy to me. It is dependent on precise timing too much.

Comment: Yes, I already did that, everytime the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` was printed is 9, no other number showed up.

Comment: What about the `Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread` property? True or false?

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread` is `false` everytime.

Comment: Then it is probably a dedicated thread, and the events do not overlap.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I think probably this is the reason: when the program run to the code blocking to receive, the system move to another program, this cause my program can't receive data in time. Do you think so?  If I can't find a way to stop the system move to another program, I'll try the asynchronous receiving method, althouth this is not suitable for my application.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb: UDP data is the one that **CAN** be lost, and the system **MUST** be designed a way to overcome that losses. Otherwise, another protocol to be employed, like TCP with built-in acknowledgements & retries, or SCTP, etc.

Given that, pursuing a goal of UDP stability is a false target. Despite your efforts, sooner or later the system will meet a situation where particular UDP packet is lost. Maybe not by sender nor receiver fault (sic!). That may happen on an interim router somewhere in-between because everyone agrees UDP can be dropped eventually.

Comment: Yes, I found the problem you mentioned. Since the two computer was connected directely and the cable is short than 5m,  so the data loss should be acceptable. In fact, I tested that, if the computer only run my program, data loss is less than 0.01%(acturally is not loss, just timeout, most of the lost data will be received in next cycles), this is acceptable. The problem is when another operation is performed in the computer in the same time, the timeout event is Increase rapidly. In another word, my program is affected by other apps. Is this normal in Windows 10 system?

Comment: Not every operation performed is affected the program, only if operations that cause cpu usage reaching 40% or more can affect.